# A standard deck of 52 playing cards is shuffled and the cards are dealt face up one at a time until an ace appears.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Determine how many cards are needed to make the probability that an ace appears greater than 1/2.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that an ace does not appear for the first card is $\frac{48}{52}$ after two cards it is $\frac{48}{52}\times \frac{47}{51}$ so that after $k$ cards it is $P_k=\frac{48\times 47\times ...(49-k)}{52\times 51\times ...(53-k)}=\frac{(52-k)\times (51-k)\times(50-k)\times(49-k)}{52\times 51\times 50\times 49}$ - the last for $k\ge 4$.  The solution is find smallest $k$ for which $P_k\lt 1/2$.

Comment: $P_8=.501$, $P_9=.456$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ equal the count of draws until the first ace appears.

Evaluate $\mathsf P(X>x)$ for any $x\in\{1,\ldots,49\}$

> $\mathsf P(X{>}x) $ is the probability that the four aces are among the later $52-x$ positions, when placing the four aces among the 52 positions without bias.

> $$\mathsf P(X{>}x) = \dfrac{\binom{52-x}{4}}{\binom {52}4} = \dfrac{(52-x)(51-x)(50-x)(49-x)}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49}$$

Find $\min\{m:\mathsf P(X{>}m)\lt 1/2\}$

Comment: If you could clarify on this that would be great! Sorry I am just extremely confused about this problem.